# Why is only the first trigger time correct?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am trying to build a trigger to be run every Friday at 11:59 PM. I am using Quartz .NET v2.2.4. My time-zone is +8:00. Here's what I've come up with.

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()                
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x=> x
                                           .OnDaysOfTheWeek(DayOfWeek.Friday)
                                           .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(23, 59))
                                           .WithRepeatCount(-1)
                                           )
            .Build();

DateTimeOffset origin = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
DateTimeOffset end = origin.AddDays(100);

IList<DateTimeOffset> dates = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimesBetween(trigger as IOperableTrigger, null, origin, end);

foreach(var date in dates)
{
   Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());
}
```

However, the problem is that this prints the following

```
9/13/2013 11:59:00 PM +08:00
9/20/2013 3:59:00 PM +00:00
9/27/2013 3:59:00 PM +00:00
10/4/2013 3:59:00 PM +00:00
10/11/2013 3:59:00 PM +00:00
```

I understand that `11:59:00 PM +08:00` is equal to `3:59:00 PM +00:00`. But is there any reason why it's printed as such? I'd sleep better if the rest had the same time and time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the dates are equivalent. Some are expressed in UTC, some in localtime.

You can convert them to your local time by calling `ToLocalTime()`

```cs
foreach (var date in dates)
    Console.WriteLine (date.ToLocalTime().ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming! :)